# Session in Symfony 2.1

Tags: session, symfony

I have problem with a session in Symfony 2.1 for a site inside Symfony (in one controller).
I set the session like this:

```
 $this->get("session")
 ->set('UserMongoId', $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());
```

After that in another file (inside the web folder of Symfony) outside symfony 2.1, I do
this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('rpod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
$session->start();
var_dump ($session);

$user_id = $session->get("UserMongoId");
```

However I received null, and I dont know how to make it work, any ideas?

now I trying MongoDbSessionHandler and storage the session in db with mongo

Comment: It looks like you create a whole new session in your shell script.  Where are you expecting it to get the session id from?

Comment: Ok , so without session start, but still I can see anything. The point is that with symony2 and only session_start();var_dump ( $_SESSION) I could see the variables now with symfony 2.1 nothing...

Comment: I understand the problem better now.  Symfony 2.1 uses a new session interface:  http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html

Comment: exactly that is the problem. Do you know how I can fix? I trying to storage the session in db with mongo, and later only get the session ( if the user are in session ), but any bundle for the moment stable in symfony 2.1

Comment: check this web site http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/11/05/storing-sessions-in-mongodb-with-symfony2/ but doesnt work for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get it store the session in db with mongo:

1.- service.yml

```
parameters:
    mongo.session.options:
        database: quorra_session
        collection: session
services:
    mongo.connection:
        class: MongoDoctrine\MongoDB\Connection
        factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager
        factory_method: getConnection
        calls:
           - [initialize, []]
    mongo:
        class: Mongo
        factory_service: mongo.connection
        factory_method: getMongo

    session.handler.mongo:
          class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler
          arguments: [@mongo, %mongo.session.options%]
```

2.- confing.yml add :

```
  framework:
        session:
            handler_id: session.handler.mongo
```

3.- after that doctrinemongo db with MongoDbSessionHandler will save all the session automatically in db perfect if we are going to work with direferents servers. will be something like that:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e60da9893ad520a11a7fd7"), "sess_data" : BinData(2,"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"), "sess_id" : "f9a98866cd99a33d61204413b68d6ca5", "sess_time" : { "t" : 1357254155000, "i" : 3 } }
```

4.- In one file outside symfony 2.1 ( i have the file now in web for not load the components )

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

//$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$mongo = new Mongo();

$options["database"] = "quorra_session";
$options["collection"] = "session";

$mongoSession = new MongoDbSessionHandler($mongo,$options);
$data = $mongoSession->read($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);
```

and the variable data has all the session for this user.

5.- Now, the next step is send to this last file the access_token_secret and check it in the result of $data = $mongoSession->read($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);

works for me, I'm waiting for your comments

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
$session->start();
```

with

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

Because you need to take the session object you created with Request::createFromGlobals();, and not a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your second block of code creates a new $session variable.  Obviously its values will be null. You need to assign $session in the second block by retrieving it somehow.

Comment: Do you mean send the session somehow ? that is not the way otherwise i use a cookie, no a session... or how you say ? thanks :)